# Can someone explain to me what to do here

Tags: c, loops, nested

I don't want the answer I want to know how to do it.
The efficiency of the algorithm `doIt` can be expressed as O(f(n))=n^3. Calculate the efficiency of the following program segment exactly and by using the big-O notation.

```
for (i=1; i<=n+1; i++)
    for (j=1; j<n, j++)
        doIt (...)
```

The example he gave us wasn't anything like this he just drew several squares inside of other squares which showed us that it was a nested loop. He didn't give us any type of code like the one in the problem. He just wrote

> Alg(m, n, k, l)=3n^3
>   M=1n, N=1 2n, K=1n, L=1n^2
>   n^2*n*2n*n*3n^3=6n^8=O(n^8)

So, I'm assuming that this is a nested loop and the highest it goes to is n^3.
Or can someone write the code for the example so I can understand it better?

Comment: The code sample appears to be cut off - would you please expand?  Also, indenting your code will make it monospace so we can read it more easily.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i=1; i<=n+1; i++)
for (j=1; j<n, j++)
    doIt (...)
```

As you mentioned the worst-case complexity is given to be O(n^3).

So, in case of nested loops, the main thing to focus is that the first loop guides the inner loop,i.e., the inner loop will generally run no. of iterations(not necessarily always) than the outer loop!

As in your question, the outer loop runs for i=1 to i=n+1---`n+1 times`. Similarly, the inner loop runs for j=1 to j < n --- **n-1 iterations on each iteration of outer loop** .
Also, the function doIt() is inside the inner loop with complexity of order O(n^3).

Next, n+1 iterations are of order O(n) as per worst-case complexity.

Similarly, n-1 iterations are of order of O(n) as per worst-case complexity!

Hence, the overall worst-case complexity = **`O(n)*O(n)*O(n^3)` = `O(n^5)`**...

If you're unable to understand,please leave a comment below!